# Why webView.getContentHeight() < webView.computeVerticalScrollRange()?

Tags: android, webview

I'm currently working with webview and I've come across unexpected behaviour: webView's vertical scroll range is higher than content height. Values from my debugger:

```
getContentHeight()               5123
computeVerticalScrollRange()     6820
```

How is that possible?

The following is something I expect to be true:

```
verticalScrollRange + webviewHeight = contentHeight
```

Why my webview is not in accordance with this?

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[computeVerticalScrollRange()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#computeVerticalScrollRange()) uses *arbitrary* units in the docs. There is no guarantee that they will match up with other units such as pixels.